# Correct permission for nginx proxy to access uwsgi socket?

Tags: python, nginx, server, file-permissions, uwsgi

I followed through DigitalOcean's [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) to setup a flask server using wsgi and nginx but my nginx sever cant access the uwsgi socket.

The error log is as follows:

```
2017/01/15 21:11:39 [crit] 1565#1565: *1 connect() to unix:/root/fib/fib.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: <IP>, server: <IP>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/root/fib/fib.sock:", host: <IP>
2017/01/15 21:11:40 [crit] 1565#1565: *1 connect() to unix:/root/fib/fib.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: <IP>, server: <IP>, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/root/fib/fib.sock:", host: <IP>, referrer: "<IP>"
```

My uwsgi ini file is:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = fib.sock
chmod-socket = 666
uid = root
gid = www-data
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

My nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <SERVER_IP_HIDDEN>;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/root/fib/fib.sock;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the correct permission settings to allow nginx to access the socket file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn a bit more about Unix hierarchy ([Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/hier.7.html), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), [OSX](http://scottlab.ucsc.edu/xtal/wiki/index.php/The_Filesystem_Structure)). You should place your socket file in either `/var/lib/uwsgi` or `/var/run` depending on flavor.

No one but root can access root's home directory for good reasons.

When in doubt, use [namei](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82361/view-permission-owner-of-full-directory-tree#113823).